# Render a <Text> as <p> with fluent ui react

Tags: fluentui-react

I would like to be able to render the ms fluent-ui  as a paragraph instead of the default span for accessibility reasons but the documentation is very unclear on what exact input is expected and in what format. I would expect something like this:

```
<Text as={<p />}>
  test
</Text>
```

or:

```
<Text as={(someProps) => <p>{someProps}</p>}>
  test
</Text>
```

Can anyone help me out with how this is supposed to be done?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path with second example. The problem is you need `React Component` instead to return directly `<p>` tag.

```js
// Custom Paragraph Component
const Paragraph = ({ children }) => <p>{children}</p>

<Text as={Paragraph}>Test</Text>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/wvPQzBQ?editors=0010) working example.